# Gradle downloads all dependencies again for each refresh

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

So i have a build.gradle file like the following.
And for each time i refresh gradle it downloads all dependencies again and also compiles them again..... Pls help this is getting really frustrating....

```
ext.versionProps = new Properties()
ext.versionFile = "src/main/resources/version.properties"
ext.globalVersion = "null"
file(versionFile).withInputStream { versionProps.load(it) }

setVersion("${versionProps.getProperty("major")}." +
        "${versionProps.getProperty("minor")}." +
        "${versionProps.getProperty("patch")}(" +
        "${versionProps.getProperty("commit")})")

apply from: "/gradle/version.gradle"

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.3.31"
    ext.tornadofx_version = "1.7.18"
    ext.junit_version = "5.1.0"
    ext.testfx_version = "4.0.15-alpha"
    ext.hamcrest_version = "2.0.0.0"
    ext.loadui_version = "3.1.2"
    ext.guava_version = "22.0"
    ext.junit_plugin = "1.1.0"
    ext.sonarqube_plugin = "2.7"
    ext.launch4j_plugin = "2.4.4"
    ext.usb4java = "1.3.0"
    ext.hid4java = "0.5.0"

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "org.junit.platform:junit-platform-gradle-plugin:$junit_plugin"
        classpath "org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:$sonarqube_plugin"
        classpath "edu.sc.seis.gradle:launch4j:$launch4j_plugin"
    }
}

apply plugin: "java"
apply plugin: "kotlin"
apply plugin: "application"
apply plugin: "org.sonarqube"
apply plugin: "jacoco"
apply plugin: "edu.sc.seis.launch4j"

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
    compile "io.github.microutils:kotlin-logging:1.6.26"
    compile "org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.26"
    compile "org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.7.26"
    compile "no.tornado:tornadofx:$tornadofx_version"

    testCompile "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:$junit_version"
    testRuntime "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:$junit_version"
    testCompile "org.testfx:testfx-junit5:$testfx_version"
    testCompile "org.testfx:testfx-core:$testfx_version"
    testCompile "org.loadui:testFx:$loadui_version"
    testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:2.27.0"
}
```

I have no clue why this is happening.

I am using the gradle wrapper and i am not admin on my Windows 7 machine.

Some more informations:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 5.2.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2019-02-08 19:00:10 UTC
Revision:     f02764e074c32ee8851a4e1877dd1fea8ffb7183

Kotlin DSL:   1.1.3
Kotlin:       1.3.20
Groovy:       2.5.4
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.13 compiled on July 10 2018
JVM:          1.8.0_202 (Oracle Corporation 25.202-b08)
OS:           Windows 7 6.1 amd64
```

Some pictures of IntelliJ:
[image]
[image]
[image]
The hole refresh takes between 5-10 minutes...

Comment: Can you include the output that makes you state that "gradle it downloads all dependencies again and also compiles them again"?

Comment: sure give me a minute :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to configure the Gradle build environment, gradle.properties in project root directory.

```
org.gradle.caching=true
```

When set to true, Gradle will reuse task outputs from any previous build, when possible, resulting is much faster builds.